# How to test the class property of a child component?

Tags: angular, testing

I am looking for a way to test if a child component has a specific class in a tested component. It's probably best to show it by example.

The parent component is a keyboard component with an HTML excerpt as shown below, it's named `EnglishKeyboardComponent` with the corresponding `english-keyboard.component.html` (it contains keys for the English phonetic symbols of the International Phonetic Alphabet; the symbols come from the respective class attribute).

```
...
<div class="col p-2">
  <app-key [key]="'F'" [tooltip]="'(a)rrive'" class="{{getFontClass()}}"></app-key>
</div>
...
```

The `getFontClass()` returns the class to be used for the English keys.

Now I would like to test these `app-key` elements and ensure that each has a key, a tooltip and a class defined, the class must equal the the font class defined in the `EnglishKeyboardComponent` (the `getFontClass()` method).

The key and the tooltip are properties of the KeyComponent and I could test it this way for example:

```
const appKeys = fixture.debugElement.queryAll(By.directive(KeyComponent));
for (const appKey of appKeys) {
  expect(appKey.componentInstance.key).toBeTruthy();
  expect(appKey.componentInstance.tooltip).toBeTruthy();
}
```

I could not figure out how to test the class attribute. I another test of another component I could test something similar like so:

```
const buttonEl = fixture.nativeElement.querySelector('button');
expect(buttonEl.attributes.getNamedItem('title').value).toEqual('(c)ool');
```

This does not work with the `KeyComponent`, ideally I would be able to something like:

```
expect(appKey.attributes.getNamedItem('class')).toEqual(component.getFontClass());
```

Would someone happen to know a way to test the class attribute of the `app-key` element?

###Update###

I add a link to [the source file](https://github.com/Elyasin/phonetik/blob/f4fc764f457fa3fd3fbfbaec0a2c21b67dc2dab6/src/app/keyboard/english-keyboard/english-keyboard.component.spec.ts#L38) on Github, you can browse the app's source code too.

Answer (score 1):

You could check the `nativeElement.classList`

```js
expect(appKey.nativeElement.classList.contains(component.getFontClass())).toEqual(true);
```

or

```js
expect(appKey.classes).toContain(component.getFontClass());
```

Comment: Thank you eko. I tried it but it did not help. I tried to output the `appKey.nativeElement`  and it turns out to be an empty `HTMLElement`. If you think maybe I should provide more information I'd be happy to provide.

Comment: Hmm maybe covering the basics might help. Are you importing this component/module in the test suite or are you using a `NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA`? Does the html have any ngIfs that might cause not rendering this element?

Comment: I am importing it in the test suite. I do not use `NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA`. The HTML does not have an `*ngIf` (neither the `EnglishKeyboard` nor the `Key`).

Comment: I will try to create a Stackblitz when I have time.